# Observer display return to frontend

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I would like to display the result from Observer to every page, any way I can do it?

app/code/MyVendor/GeoIp/Observer/GeoObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace MyModule\GeoIp\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use MyModule\GeoIp\Helper\GeoLocation;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class GeoObserver implements ObserverInterface {

public function __construct(
    GeoLocation $helperGeoLocation,
    LayoutInterface $layout
){
    $this->helpGeoLocation = $helperGeoLocation;
    $this->layout = $layout;
}

public function execute(Observer $observer)
{

    $displaytext = $this->helpGeoLocation->getCountryCodeByIp();

    $result = "<p> GEO: $displaytext </p>";

    return $result;
}

}
```

Comment: Why not adding this code directly into a block rather than an observer ? And then just call the block to everypage ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create event : events.xml (app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/events.xml)
code:
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="page_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\allPage" />
</event>
```

Create the class file with name allPage.php app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Observer/allPage.php

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class allPage implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
       //Your Code
    }
}

This code will execute for all frontend pages.
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans, but any way to return it to a custom block?